# Using My Mac as a webserver for my VMware VM

Tags: virtualization

So, I have my Mac running VMware Fusion and I have a Windows XP VM running.

Currently the VM Network setup is NAT, my Mac is already setup as a web server.

I'd like to be able to access the Mac from the vm via the web browser (for some testing).

If the VM is set to use NAT is there a standard IP address I can use from the VM to get to the Mac regardless of what network I might be on?  I might be at work and have an IP address of 10.1.*.* or I might be at home and have an IP address of 192.168.*.*

What are my options?

Update:
At work I am on an AD domain

When I switch to Bridged networking I can see my Mac from the VM using my Mac's IP address.

I was hoping (and thinking) there would be an IP address that I could use regardless of where I am at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for; originally found [on this thread](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/158697):

> That is exactly what NAT does. It puts your virtual machine on
>   separate network, vmnet8. Go to Terminal and type ifconfig. You will
>   see the IP address for your host in vmnet8.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried 'machinename.local?' (eg mymac.local)

I have a similar setup (and many many variations thereof) and usually the Windows VM can see the Mac via the address 'millie.local', where millie is the machine name.

If you go and look at the 'Sharing' tab of the System Preferences program, you should see what '.local' name your machine will appear as.

This doesn't work so well with Server 2003 (and presumably Server 2008) as .local has a different meaning with Windows AD networks, but it ought to be fine with XP.

Comment: So I looked and my .local name is something crazy like M-MacBook-Pro.local and when I am on the network at my office (which runs on a windows AD) I can't ping M-MacBook-Pro.local or get to it via the browser.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the update and the edit to the question. I'll have a think and get back to you... pretty sure I've had this working regardless of whether the macbook is on an AD network or not. I do tend to use the VMs bridged all the time, not NAT, but even so...